# Example of cumulative distribution function and the empirical distribution function

Tags: r, cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

A random of 100 rolls of the die. The outcomes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, occurred 13, 19, 10, 17, 14, 27 times, respectively. Calculate the cumulative distribution function and the empirical distribution function? Plot both function in R?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF) is based on data.
It is a 'stairstep' function. For your data, starting from height $0$ below $x = 1,$
it jumps up by $13/100$ at $x = 1,$ by an additional $19/100$ at $x = 2,$
and so on, until reaching a height of $1$ at $x = 6.$

In R, your rolls of the die (sorted by increasing numbers on die faces), can
be represented as follows:

```
x = rep(1:6, c(13, 19, 10, 17, 14, 27))
table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
13 19 10 17 14 27
```

Then we can plot the ECDF as follows:

```
plot(ecdf(x), main="ECDF of 100 Rolls of a Die")
```

[image]

We can represent the CDF of a fair die as shown below. And then plot this
CDF (dotted red line) on the same axes as the ECDF. Centers
of open dots are exact values of the CDF. For as few as 100 tosses, agreement between the observed ECDF and the theoretical
CDF seems very good.

```
k = 1:6;  cdf = (1:6)/6
plot(ecdf(x), main="ECDF of 100 Rolls with Theoretical CDF")
 lines(k, cdf, type="s", col="red", lty = "dotted")
 points(k, cdf, col="red")
```

[image]

To do your own plotting on graph paper, you might start by
making tables of the ECDF and CDF at points $x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.$

Comment: Thank you so much!